# Jfrog Xray Violations should not occure for libraries where there is no fix version

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

We have set of policies (security and license) in our jfrog instance and have enabled with watchers for our builds with these policies. So we have noticed that there vulnerabilities are shown in the security and license tabs after the xray scan and according to our policy settings the violations are populated. But its noticed that still some vulnerabilities and violations are showing with no fix version information on those items. So our management want to exclude those vulnerabilities\violations from list where we dont have proper fix version information. I tried multiple policy settings and it didn't help me.

Comment: which version of Xray and Artifactory you are using? There is a special rule to exclude violations where there is no fix version.

Comment: Artifactory version:- 7.41.4, Xray- 3.52.4

Comment: @shaibz Can u guide me how we can achieve this?

Comment: You should have this feature, as it was added in Xray 3.43.
Basically you can do this through the Administration tab -> Xray -> Watches & Policies and then you can create or edit any policy -> Add or edit a rule -> On policy Rules screen you should have a checkbox called 'Generate violations only when fixed versions are available" which is required to be checked (you might need scroll down a bit).
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Creating+Xray+Policies+and+Rules